# how to make Image.open in python work with the root direcotry

Tags: python

i am trying to code pdf viewer with python (level = beginner).
I dont know if my code is correct but i want to open image from the root directory with "Image.open" ,or if you have another solution this will be great.

Thanks for reading this and trying to help, have a nice day :)

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import glob
import os

def path():
    
    path1 = "/home/d*rew*lf/Documents/Project/Python/EbookReader/img/*.png"
    path2 = "/home/d*rew*lf/Documents/Project/Python/EbookReader/img/"

    a = glob.glob(path1)
    b = os.listdir(path2)
    
    print(a)
    print()
    print(b)

    return a



result=path()

i=len(result)



root=Tk()

#window resolution
root.geometry("800x600")

#insertion of images

x=0

while x<i:
    
    print(x)
    
    img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(result[x]))
    x=x+1
    Label=Button(width=300,height=500,image=img)
    Label.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So what is the problem with your code? Does it work?

Comment: "Are you sharing your work" or "are your asking for assistance" or "are you saying this is how its done"?

Comment: no its doesnt work cuz the ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(result[x])) doesnt support reltive path so i asked if there is any solution to this problem in python or i am doing something wrong